# Xtabs to xts in R

Tags: r, xts, xtabs

I have data of class `xtabs` in R that looks like bellow:

[image]

```
 Last Update    1Y    2Y    3Y    4Y    5Y    7Y   10Y   15Y   20Y   25Y
  2011-04-15 0.666 1.315 2.105 2.780 3.355 4.180 4.807 5.233 5.411 5.504
  2011-04-18 0.653 1.280 2.053 2.727 3.311 4.142 4.785 5.206 5.395 5.491
  2011-04-19 0.652 1.273 2.053 2.730 3.312 4.143 4.771 5.201 5.380 5.468
  2011-04-20 0.655 1.293 2.092 2.766 3.356 4.181 4.796 5.227 5.402 5.490
  2011-04-21 0.644 1.281 2.079 2.772 3.337 4.171 4.805 5.231 5.409 5.485
  2011-04-25 0.635 1.261 2.047 2.734 3.314 4.141 4.762 5.181 5.361 5.449
            Tenor
 Last Update   30Y
  2011-04-15 5.504
  2011-04-18 5.486
  2011-04-19 5.461
  2011-04-20 5.503
  2011-04-21 5.503
  2011-04-25 5.494
```

The function that I am trying to use is `Nelson.Siegel` from package `YieldCurve`. The input structure of the function should be as I have but in `xts` format. I tried `as.xts()` but it is not working. How can I change the type from `xtabs` to `xts` maintaining the same structure?

Comment: did you have a look at [tsbox](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsbox/vignettes/tsbox.html)?

Comment: can you `dput` your `xtabs` object? besides `xtabs`, there are other ways to reshape your data. try googling for reshape my data from long to wide

Comment: @Waldi The package doesn't have xtabs to xts conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is not much you can do about converting xtabs to xts format. I reconstructed the structure using reshape(), converted it into a data frame and at last used xts() to change the type to xts format.